# Querying and Filtering Nested Arrays in Mongo DB (Shell)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query, document

I have the following 3 documents in my mongo collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "docId" : "089b0b4e-3096-4111-b074-a6713f58bfab"
    }, 
    "items" : [
        {
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : null
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "c26672a8-b5b1-42bf-8ec5-476db4bd3975"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "products" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "681a8658-768a-4665-bf51-ef556f881646"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "docId" : "32d2e389-d377-4552-a3c6-dc52d2abaa6c"
    }, 
    "items" : [
        {
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : null
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "bea6baef-d8c0-4e7c-9b49-98af4a4f53e8"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "products" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : null
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "8d598e72-cd72-4d3b-aa2c-1278ad4acce1"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "docId" : "69effab9-2071-4c9b-a49d-dd38384991d9"
    }, 
    "items" : [
        {
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : null
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming a valid productId is one that exists and is not null, I need my query to return only the documents that contain at least one valid productId and at the same time the products array should only include those valid product documents only like so:
(Note that only 2 documents are returned with a total of 4 products)

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "docId" : "089b0b4e-3096-4111-b074-a6713f58bfab"
    }, 
    "items" : [
        {
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "c26672a8-b5b1-42bf-8ec5-476db4bd3975"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "products" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "681a8658-768a-4665-bf51-ef556f881646"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "docId" : "32d2e389-d377-4552-a3c6-dc52d2abaa6c"
    }, 
    "items" : [
        {
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "bea6baef-d8c0-4e7c-9b49-98af4a4f53e8"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "products" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "productId" : "8d598e72-cd72-4d3b-aa2c-1278ad4acce1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this but does not seem to work

```
collection.find({    
    "items": {
         $elemMatch: {
             "products": {
                 $elemMatch: {
                    "_id.productId": { $exists: true, $ne: null }
                 }
             }
         }   
    }
})
```

Is this not possible to do with the `find` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may go with aggregations

- Your productId is inside the nested array. We use `$map` to loop it.
- `$filter` to filter the objects using condition
- If your products array has any matching element to the condition ($anyElementTrue), we add another variable `hasProductId` is true or false with teh help of `$mergeObjects`
- The condition is productId cannot be `null` and `undefined`
- You will get `hasProductId` in each objects of document
- `$match` helps to if anything true, then get the document
- `$project` helps to remove the temp field `$hasProductId`

here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$items",
          "in": {
            products: {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$$this.products",
                "as": "product",
                "cond": {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      $ne: [
                        "$$product._id.productId",
                        null
                      ],
                      
                    },
                    {
                      $ne: [
                        "$$product._id.productId",
                        undefined
                      ],
                      
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "items.products": {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KSc_F4tFq71)**

Comment: This does not seem to work in the mongo playground at least

Comment: What is the issue you facing there?

Comment: I can still see products with empty product ids and product ids set to null in the returned arrays. The query is correct in selecting only the two top level documents which only contain at least one valid product